# Finding special characters in MySQL database

Tags: mysql

Does anyone know of a quick and easy way to locate special characters that didn't get correctly converted when data was imported into MySQL.

I think this an issue due to data encoding (e.g. Latin-1 vs. UTF-8).  Regardless where the issue first occurred, I'm stuck with junk in my data that I need to remove.

Comment: How did you *import* the data in MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

There's unlikely to be an easy function for this, because for example, a broken UTF-8 special character will consist of two valid ISO-8859-1 characters. So while there are patterns of what those broken characters look like, there is no sure-fire way of identifying them.

You could build a search+replace function to replace the most common occurrences in your language (e.g. `Ãœ` for `Ü` if imported from UTF-8 into ISO-8859-1).

That said, it would be best to restart the import with the correct settings, if at all possible.

Comment: Unfortunately reimporting the data at this point isn't really an option.  And there aren't many of these special characters sprinkled throughout the data.  But even writing a search-n-replace script, you need to have a starting list of special characters to replace.  That's the list I'm trying to create.